# How to click on a random link inside a table in watir webdriver?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am using salesforce application. I want to click on a link inside a table.The link is randomly generated.And there are 2 -3 links inside the table.but I want to click on specific one.

below is my code:

```
DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html class="ext-strict" style="" xmlns:ui="http://www.salesforce.com/ui/accent/sfdccmp/ui" xmlns:config="http://www.salesforce.com/ui/accent/sfdccmp/ui" xmlns:facet="http://www.salesforce.com/ui/accent/sfdccmp/ui" xmlns:data="http://www.salesforce.com/ui/accent/sfdccmp/data" xmlns:chatter="http://www.salesforce.com/ui/accent/sfdccmp/chatter" xmlns:sfdc="http://www.salesforce.com/ui/accent/sfdccmp/sfdc"><head> … </head><body class="hasMotif contractTab  detailPage  ext-gecko ext-gecko3 sfdcBody brandQuaternaryBgr" onbeforeunload="if(this.bodyOnBeforeUnload){var s=bodyOnBeforeUnload();if(s)return s;}" onfocus="if(this.bodyOnFocus)bodyOnFocus();" onunload="if(this.bodyOnUnload)bodyOnUnload();" onload="if(this.bodyOnLoad)bodyOnLoad();">
  <!-- Main Body Starts Here -->
<form id="sessiontimeout" onsubmit="if (window.ffInAlert) { return false; }" name="sessiontimeout" method="post"> … </form><script> … </script><a class="navSkipLink zen-skipLink zen-assistiveText" href="#skiplink"> … </a><div id="contentWrapper"><div id="AppBodyHeader" class="bPageHeader"><table id="phHeader" class="phHeader brandZeronaryBgr" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> … </table><div class="zen"><div id="tabContainer" class="zen-hasTabOrganizer zen-headerBottom brdPalette" role="navigation"><h1 class="zen-assistiveText"> … </h1><nav><ul id="tabBar" class="zen-inlineList zen-tabMenu"><li id="home_Tab" class="zen-firstItem"> … </li><li id="File_Tab"> … </li><li id="Account_Tab"> … </li><li id="Lead_Tab"> … </li><li id="Opportunity_Tab"> … </li><li id="01r30000001KGS2_Tab"> … </li><li id="report_Tab"> … </li><li id="Dashboard_Tab"> … </li><li id="Chatter_Tab"> … </li><li id="01ra00000014PLY_Tab"> … </li><li id="Case_Tab"> … </li><li id="AllTab_Tab"> … </li><li id="MoreTabs_Tab" class="zen-notNeeded zen-lastItem zen-moreTabs" data-uidsfdc="59"> … </li></ul></nav></div></div></div><div class="bodyDiv brdPalette brandPrimaryBrd"><table id="bodyTable" class="outer" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <!-- Start page content table -->
<tbody><tr><td id="sidebarCell" class=" sidebarCell sidebarCollapsible sidebarCollapsed"> … </td><td id="bodyCell" class="oRight">
  <!-- Start page content -->
<a name="skiplink"> … </a><div class="bPageTitle"><div class="ptBody"><div class="content"><img class="pageTitleIcon" title="Contract" alt="Contract" src="/s.gif"></img><h1 class="pageType"> … </h1><h2 class="pageDescription">
   CTR-00276843
</h2><div class="blank"> … </div></div><div class="links"> … </div></div><div id="section_header" class="metadata"> … </div><div id="chatterfeedshell" class="chatterfeedshell"> … </div><script> … </script><div class="ptBreadcrumb"></div></div><script type="text/javascript"> … </script><div id="RLPanelShadow" class="RLPanelShadow" style="display: none;"> … </div><div class="listHoverLinks" style="visibility: visible;"> … </div><script> … </script><script> … </script><div id="ep" class="bPageBlock brandSecondaryBrd bDetailBlock secondaryPalette"><div class="pbHeader"> … </div><div class="pbBody"><div id="errorDiv_ep" class="pbError" style="display: none"> … </div><div class="pbSubsection"><table class="detailList" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr><td class="labelCol">
  Contract Name
</td><td id="Name_ilecell" class="dataCol col02 inlineEditWrite" tabindex="0" onmouseover="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" onmouseout="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);" onkeypress="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun && event && event.keyCode==KEY_ENTER) sfdcPage.dblClickField(event, this);" onfocus="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" ondblclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.dblClickField(event, this);" onclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.clickField(event, this);" onblur="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);"> … </td><td class="labelCol">
  Status
</td><td id="ctrc15_ilecell" class="dataCol inlineEditWrite" tabindex="0" onmouseover="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" onmouseout="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);" onkeypress="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun && event && event.keyCode==KEY_ENTER) sfdcPage.dblClickField(event, this);" onfocus="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" ondblclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.dblClickField(event, this);" onclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.clickField(event, this);" onblur="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);"><div id="ctrc15_ileinner"> … </div></td></tr><tr><td class="labelCol"> … </td><td id="ctrc2_ilecell" class="dataCol col02 inlineEditLock" onmouseover="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" onmouseout="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);" onfocus="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" ondblclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.dblClickField(event, this);" onclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.clickField(event, this);" onblur="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);"> … </td><td class="labelCol">
  Contract Start Date
</td><td id="ctrc5_ilecell" class="dataCol inlineEditWrite" tabindex="0" onmouseover="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" onmouseout="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);" onkeypress="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun && event && event.keyCode==KEY_ENTER) sfdcPage.dblClickField(event, this);" onfocus="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" ondblclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.dblClickField(event, this);" onclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.clickField(event, this);" onblur="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);"><div id="ctrc5_ileinner"> … </div></td></tr><tr> … </tr><tr><td class="labelCol">
  Opportunity
</td><td id="CF00Na000000ASdVq_ilecell" class="dataCol col02 inlineEditWrite" tabindex="0" onmouseover="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" onmouseout="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);" onkeypress="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun && event && event.keyCode==KEY_ENTER) sfdcPage.dblClickField(event, this);" onfocus="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" ondblclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.dblClickField(event, this);" onclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.clickField(event, this);" onblur="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);"> … </td><td class="labelCol">
  Owner Expiration Notice
</td><td id="ctrc13_ilecell" class="dataCol inlineEditWrite" tabindex="0" onmouseover="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" onmouseout="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);" onkeypress="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun && event && event.keyCode==KEY_ENTER) sfdcPage.dblClickField(event, this);" onfocus="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" ondblclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.dblClickField(event, this);" onclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.clickField(event, this);" onblur="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);"> … </td></tr><tr><td class="labelCol"> … </td><td id="00Na000000ATFrm_ilecell" class="dataCol col02 inlineEditWrite" tabindex="0" onmouseover="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" onmouseout="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);" onkeypress="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun && event && event.keyCode==KEY_ENTER) sfdcPage.dblClickField(event, this);" onfocus="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" ondblclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.dblClickField(event, this);" onclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.clickField(event, this);" onblur="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);"> … </td><td class="labelCol"> … </td><td id="ctrc1_ilecell" class="dataCol"> … </td></tr><tr><td class="labelCol"> … </td><td id="00Na000000ASdVv_ilecell" class="dataCol col02 inlineEditWrite" tabindex="0" onmouseover="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" onmouseout="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);" onkeypress="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun && event && event.keyCode==KEY_ENTER) sfdcPage.dblClickField(event, this);" onfocus="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" ondblclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.dblClickField(event, this);" onclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.clickField(event, this);" onblur="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);"> … </td><td class="labelCol">
  Billing Representative
</td><td id="CF00Na000000ASdVd_ilecell" class="dataCol inlineEditWrite" tabindex="0" onmouseover="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" onmouseout="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);" onkeypress="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun && event && event.keyCode==KEY_ENTER) sfdcPage.dblClickField(event, this);" onfocus="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" ondblclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.dblClickField(event, this);" onclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.clickField(event, this);" onblur="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);"> … </td></tr><tr> … </tr><tr><td class="labelCol"> … </td><td id="00Na000000AT3UN_ilecell" class="dataCol col02 inlineEditLock" onmouseover="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" onmouseout="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);" onfocus="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" ondblclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.dblClickField(event, this);" onclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.clickField(event, this);" onblur="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);"> … </td><td class="labelCol"> … </td><td id="00Na000000AT3Ty_ilecell" class="dataCol inlineEditLock" onmouseover="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" onmouseout="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);" onfocus="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" ondblclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.dblClickField(event, this);" onclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.clickField(event, this);" onblur="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);"> … </td></tr><tr> … </tr><tr> … </tr></tbody></table></div><div id="head_01Ba000000DcapR_ep" class="pbSubheader brandTertiaryBrd tertiaryPalette"><img id="img_01Ba000000DcapR" class="hideListButton" title="Hide Section - Pricing Change Details" tabindex="0" style="cursor:pointer;" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode=='13')twistSection(this);" onclick="twistSection(this);" name="Pricing Change Details" alt="Hide Section - Pricing Change Details" src="/s.gif"></img><h3> … </h3></div><div class="pbSubsection"><table class="detailList" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> … </table></div><div id="head_01Ba000000DcapS_ep" class="pbSubheader brandTertiaryBrd tertiaryPalette"><img id="img_01Ba000000DcapS" class="hideListButton" title="Hide Section - Total Summary" tabindex="0" style="cursor:pointer;" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode=='13')twistSection(this);" onclick="twistSection(this);" name="Total Summary" alt="Hide Section - Total Summary" src="/s.gif"></img><h3> … </h3></div><div class="pbSubsection"><table class="detailList" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr> … </tr><tr><td class="labelCol">
  Annual Discount
</td><td id="00Na000000ASdZO_ilecell" class="dataCol col02 inlineEditLock" onmouseover="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" onmouseout="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);" onfocus="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" ondblclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.dblClickField(event, this);" onclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.clickField(event, this);" onblur="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);"><div id="00Na000000ASdZO_ileinner"> … </div></td><td class="labelCol">
  Total Annual
</td><td id="00Na000000ASdZT_ilecell" class="dataCol inlineEditLock" onmouseover="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" onmouseout="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);" onfocus="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" ondblclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.dblClickField(event, this);" onclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.clickField(event, this);" onblur="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);"> … </td></tr><tr> … </tr><tr> … </tr></tbody></table></div><div id="head_01Ba000000Dce1V_ep" class="pbSubheader brandTertiaryBrd tertiaryPalette"><img id="img_01Ba000000Dce1V" class="hideListButton" title="Hide Section - Quote Detail" tabindex="0" style="cursor:pointer;" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode=='13')twistSection(this);" onclick="twistSection(this);" name="Quote Detail" alt="Hide Section - Quote Detail" src="/s.gif"></img><h3> … </h3></div><div class="pbSubsection"><table class="detailList" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> … </table></div><div id="head_01Ba000000DcapT_ep" class="pbSubheader brandTertiaryBrd tertiaryPalette"><img id="img_01Ba000000DcapT" class="hideListButton" title="Hide Section - Last Active Contract Total Summary" tabindex="0" style="cursor:pointer;" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode=='13')twistSection(this);" onclick="twistSection(this);" name="Last Active Contract Total Summary" alt="Hide Section - Last Active Contract Total Summary" src="/s.gif"></img><h3> … </h3></div><div class="pbSubsection"><table class="detailList" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> … </table></div><div id="head_01Ba000000DcWtn_ep" class="pbSubheader brandTertiaryBrd tertiaryPalette"><img id="img_01Ba000000DcWtn" class="hideListButton" title="Hide Section - Additional Information" tabindex="0" style="cursor:pointer;" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode=='13')twistSection(this);" onclick="twistSection(this);" name="Additional Information" alt="Hide Section - Additional Information" src="/s.gif"></img><h3> … </h3></div><div class="pbSubsection"><table class="detailList" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> … </table></div><div id="head_01Ba000000DcapU_ep" class="pbSubheader brandTertiaryBrd tertiaryPalette"><img id="img_01Ba000000DcapU" class="hideListButton" title="Hide Section - Restaurant Address" tabindex="0" style="cursor:pointer;" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode=='13')twistSection(this);" onclick="twistSection(this);" name="Restaurant Address" alt="Hide Section - Restaurant Address" src="/s.gif"></img><h3> … </h3></div><div class="pbSubsection"><table class="detailList" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> … </table></div><div id="head_01B3000000AaoSI_ep" class="pbSubheader brandTertiaryBrd tertiaryPalette"><img id="img_01B3000000AaoSI" class="hideListButton" title="Hide Section - Address Information" tabindex="0" style="cursor:pointer;" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode=='13')twistSection(this);" onclick="twistSection(this);" name="Address Information" alt="Hide Section - Address Information" src="/s.gif"></img><h3> … </h3></div><div class="pbSubsection"><table class="detailList" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> … </table></div><div id="head_01B3000000AaoSJ_ep" class="pbSubheader brandTertiaryBrd tertiaryPalette"> … </div><div class="pbSubsection"> … </div><div id="head_01Ba000000Dejvd_ep" class="pbSubheader brandTertiaryBrd tertiaryPalette"> … </div><div class="pbSubsection"> … </div><div id="head_01B3000000AaoSK_ep" class="pbSubheader brandTertiaryBrd tertiaryPalette"> … </div><div class="pbSubsection"> … </div><div id="head_01Ba000000DcapV_ep" class="pbSubheader brandTertiaryBrd tertiaryPalette"> … </div><div class="pbSubsection"> … </div><div id="head_01B3000000AaoSL_ep" class="pbSubheader brandTertiaryBrd tertiaryPalette"> … </div><div class="pbSubsection"> … </div><div id="head_01Ba000000Dce1W_ep" class="pbSubheader brandTertiaryBrd tertiaryPalette"> … </div><div class="pbSubsection"> … </div><div id="head_01Ba000000DcapW_ep" class="pbSubheader brandTertiaryBrd tertiaryPalette"> … </div><div class="pbSubsection"> … </div></div><div class="pbBottomButtons"> … </div><div class="pbFooter secondaryPalette"> … </div></div><script src="/static/111213/js/picklist.js"></script><script> … </script>
  <!-- Begin RelatedListElement -->
<div id="800f00000006U1C_00Na000000ASdVK" class="bRelatedList"><a name="800f00000006U1C_00Na000000ASdVK_target"></a>
  <!-- Begin ListElement -->

  <!-- motif: Contract -->

  <!-- WrappingClass -->
<div class="listRelatedObject customnotabBlock"> … </div><div class="listElementBottomNav"></div><script> … </script>
  <!-- End ListElement -->
</div>
  <!-- End RelatedListElement -->

  <!-- Begin RelatedListElement -->
<div id="800f00000006U1C_00Na000000ASdVM" class="bRelatedList"><a name="800f00000006U1C_00Na000000ASdVM_target"></a>
  <!-- Begin ListElement -->

  <!-- motif: Contract -->

  <!-- WrappingClass -->
<div class="listRelatedObject Custom18Block"><div class="bPageBlock brandSecondaryBrd secondaryPalette"><div class="pbHeader"> … </div><div id="800f00000006U1C_00Na000000ASdVM_body" class="pbBody"><table class="list" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr class="headerRow"> … </tr>
  <!-- ListRow -->
<tr class="dataRow even last first" onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onfocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onblur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}"><td class="actionColumn"> … </td><th class=" dataCell  " scope="row"><a href="/a1kf00000007bl0">
  ORD-test_SS_12335_4-Jul-15-2014
</a></th><td class=" dataCell  ">
  Installed/Setup
</td><td class=" dataCell  "> … </td><td class=" dataCell  "> … </td><td class=" dataCell  "> … </td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="pbFooter secondaryPalette"> … </div></div></div><div class="listElementBottomNav"></div><script> … </script>
  <!-- End ListElement -->
</div>
  <!-- End RelatedListElement -->

  <!-- Begin RelatedListElement -->
<div id="800f00000006U1C_00Na000000ASdVR" class="bRelatedList"><a name="800f00000006U1C_00Na000000ASdVR_target"></a>
  <!-- Begin ListElement -->

  <!-- motif: Contract -->

  <!-- WrappingClass -->
<div class="listRelatedObject assetBlock"><div class="bPageBlock brandSecondaryBrd secondaryPalette"><div class="pbHeader"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr><td class="pbTitle"><img class="minWidth" width="1" height="1" title="" alt="" src="/s.gif"></img><img class="relatedListIcon" title="" alt="" src="/s.gif"></img><h3 id="800f00000006U1C_00Na000000ASdVR_title"> … </h3></td><td class="pbButton"> … </td><td class="pbHelp"> … </td></tr></tbody></table></div><div id="800f00000006U1C_00Na000000ASdVR_body" class="pbBody"> … </div><div class="pbFooter secondaryPalette"> … </div></div></div><div class="listElementBottomNav"></div><script> … </script>
  <!-- End ListElement -->
</div>
  <!-- End RelatedListElement -->

  <!-- Begin RelatedListElement -->
<div id="800f00000006U1C_RelatedActivityList" class="bRelatedList"><a name="800f00000006U1C_RelatedActivityList_target"></a>
  <!-- Begin ListElement -->

  <!-- motif: Contract -->

  <!-- WrappingClass -->
<div class="listRelatedObject taskBlock"> … </div><div class="listElementBottomNav"></div><script> … </script>
  <!-- End ListElement -->
</div>
  <!-- End RelatedListElement -->

  <!-- Begin RelatedListElement -->
<div id="800f00000006U1C_RelatedHistoryList" class="bRelatedList"> … </div>
  <!-- End RelatedListElement -->

  <!-- Begin RelatedListElement -->
<div id="800f00000006U1C_00Na000000AT3VB" class="bRelatedList"> … </div>
  <!-- End RelatedListElement -->

  <!-- Begin RelatedListElement -->
<div id="800f00000006U1C_RelatedNoteList" class="bRelatedList"><a name="800f00000006U1C_RelatedNoteList_target"></a>
  <!-- Begin ListElement -->

  <!-- motif: Contract -->

  <!-- WrappingClass -->
<div class="noStandardTab"> … </div><div class="listElementBottomNav"></div><script> … </script>
  <!-- End ListElement -->
</div>
  <!-- End RelatedListElement -->

  <!-- Begin RelatedListElement -->
<div id="800f00000006U1C_00N3000000A6gu9" class="bRelatedList"> … </div>
  <!-- End RelatedListElement -->

  <!-- Begin RelatedListElement -->
<div id="800f00000006U1C_RelatedEntityHistoryList" class="bRelatedList"><a name="800f00000006U1C_RelatedEntityHistoryList_target"></a>
  <!-- Begin ListElement -->

  <!-- motif: Contract -->

  <!-- WrappingClass -->
<div class="noStandardTab"> … </div><div class="listElementBottomNav"></div><script> … </script>
  <!-- End ListElement -->
</div>
  <!-- End RelatedListElement -->
<div class="fewerMore"> … </div><script> … </script>
  <!-- Body events -->
<script type="text/javascript"> … </script><div id="datePicker" class="datePicker"> … </div>
  <!-- End page content -->
</td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="bPageFooter noTableFooter"> … </div><div></div></div><script> … </script><script src="/jslibrary/1402506602000/sfdc/ChatterDefer.js" defer="true"></script><script src="/jslibrary/1404472812000/sfdc/Zen.js" defer="true"></script><script> … </script><script async="" defer="" src="/jslibrary/1400606638000/sfdc/SfdcSessionBase190.js"></script><iframe title="sessionserver" style="position: absolute; top: -999px; left: -999px;" src="https://test.salesforce.com/login/sessionserver190.html"></iframe><div id="devSlide" style="display: block;"> … </div><div id="InlineEditDialog" class="overlayDialog cssDialog inlineEditDialog" role="dialog" aria-live="assertive" aria-describedby="InlineEditDialogTitle" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px;"> … </div></body></html>
  <!-- page generation time: 1564ms -->



I want to click <a href="/a1kf00000007bl0">ORD-test_SS_12335_4-Jul-15-2014</a> link.
```

The UI shown as below:

Action  Order   Order Status    Project Coordinator ROS Record Type
Edit | Del  ORD-test_SS_12335_4-Jul-15-2014 Installed/Setup Marta Vovchenko     System Install

here Edit|del are links. but i want to click on ORD-test_SS_12335_4-Jul-15-2014 link.

Comment: How as a user do you know which link to click given that the link is randomly generated? Are there multiple of these rows within the table or just one row?

Comment: Its just a one row.There are 3 links inside the table.These are edit del and the link i have to click.I want to click on that link and proceed to next page.

Comment: Is there more HTML to this table? It seems strange that there is a `<tr class="headerRow">` that has no td or th elements and is not closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the link is not completely random - ie some part of "ORD-test_SS_12335_4-Jul-15-2014" should be known. For example, the "test" part does not seem random. Therefore you could try locating the link by part of its text:

```
browser.link(:text => /test/).click
```

If that does not work, you could find the table and click the on th element link:

```
table = browser.table(:class => 'list')
table.th.link.click
```

It looks there could be other th elements in the table, so you might just be able to click the last link:

```
table = browser.table(:class => 'list')
table.links.last.click
```

Comment: Hi @Justin. Appreciate your help.Here the problem is if i use your 1st solution i.e browser.link(:text => /test/).click,It clicking the 1st link with test keyword.As you can see in the HTML above there are two other links(Edit and Delete) before the link i want to click in the same table.These links are with title Edit - Record 1 - ORD-test_SS_12335_4-Jul-15-2014 and Delete - Record 1 - ORD-test_SS_12335_4-Jul-15-2014.

Comment: Regarding your 2nd and 3rd  solution ,actually there are 3 tables in the same page with class=list.The table i want to use is the 2nd table.So if i use table.links.last.click then it clicking a link in the 3rd table.

Comment: The HTML you have shown only has 1 link with text containing "test". The "Edit" and "Delete" links have the word "test" in their title attribute, but not their text, which means they would not get clicked. Regarding your second comment, `table.links.last` would actually give you the last link in the first table (not the third). At any rate, I think you will get much better answers if you give a more complete HTML sample. As you can see from the various replies you have added, there are a lot of other things on the page that we cannot take into account without seeing.

Comment: Hi @justin.Thanks for the reply. Added the complete html page above.Hope this would help.

Comment: Given the updated HTML sample, which looks like it is has had content removed, you could still use `browser.link(:text => /test/).click`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is only one table returned.

```
browser.element(:css => "th.dataCell a").click
```

or

```
browser.link(:css => "th.dataCell a").click
```

will click on just the "ORD-test_SS_12335_4-Jul-15-2014" element

If you have multiple rows it looks like you might be able to further filter selectors

```
browser.link(:css => "tr.dataRow.even th.dataCell a").click
browser.link(:css => "tr.dataRow.last th.dataCell a").click
browser.link(:css => "tr.dataRow.first th.dataCell a").click
```

Comment: Hey @Carldmitch Thanks for reply.This code is clicking on another link in that page.because that link has same class name 'dataCell'.

Comment: @sudhirswain all of the solutions given will click on the "randomly generated" link based on the code you have provided, if there are additional 'blocks' outside of the code you have provided then we would need to see that html to further assist you.